# Convert list with one item to item itself in dict value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, one-liner

For example, there is a dictionary with key-value pairs, where the values are lists with different "content". Some lists have only one element. These elements can be different types of data.

**Question:** What is the most efficient way to convert list type key values with one element into the element itself in the dict values?

**Input data**

```
{
  "key1": ["text"],
  "key2": ["text", "text"],
  "key3": [{"key0": 0}],
  "key4": [{"key0": 0, "key1": 1}],
  "key5": [],
  "key6": [[]],
  "key7": [["text"]],
  "key8": [[{"key0": 0}]]
}
```

**Expected output data**

```
{
  "key1": "text",
  "key2": ["text", "text"],
  "key3": {"key0": 0},
  "key4": {"key0": 0, "key1": 1},
  "key5": "",
  "key6": "",
  "key7": "text",
  "key8": {"key0": 0}
}
```

**What I have tried**

```
{k: v[0] for k, v in dct.items()}
```

Output of my code with the issues and comments

```
{
 'key1': 'text',
 'key2': 'text', <- ISSUE 1 should be ["text", "text"]
 'key3': {'key0': 0},
 'key4': {'key0': 0, 'key1': 1},
 'key5': <- ISSUE 2 Raises ERROR "IndexError: list index out of range" which is quite expected, should be ""
 'key6': [], <- ISSUE 3 should be ""
 'key7': ['text'], <- ISSUE 4 should be "text"
 'key8': [{'key0': 0}] <- ISSUE 5 should be {'key0': 0}
}
```

What is the most efficient way to convert dict in `Input data` to the dict in the `Expected output data`?

Comment: The expected outputs for keys 6 and 8 don't seem consistent. Why shouldn't key 8 produce `[{"key0": 0}]`

Comment: Similar question for key 7.  And key 2.

Comment: @code11, keys 7 and 8 have nested lists with one list value that is does not make any sense. if we pull out nested list with value so we get key1 case (list with one value)

Comment: @ScottHunter, key2 value has two items so it should be kept as is.

Comment: Why should key 5, which initially has an empty list, be replaced with an empty string?

Comment: @code11, `"key8": [[{"key0": 0}]]` should produce `"key8": {"key0": 0}` because `"key8": [{"key0": 0}]` output is equal to `"key3": [{"key0": 0}]` case

Comment: The keys in your actual output are off (`key5` appears twice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to tackle this problem, I concentrate on how to convert the value: I create a function called `delist` to delete the list with 1 element:

```py
def delist(value):
    while isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:
        value = value[0]
    if value == []:
        value = ""
    return value
```

Hopefully, the logic is easy enough to understand. To use it:

```py
data = {
  "key1": ["text"],
  "key2": ["text", "text"],
  "key3": [{"key0": 0}],
  "key4": [{"key0": 0, "key1": 1}],
  "key5": [],
  "key6": [[]],
  "key7": [["text"]],
  "key8": [[{"key0": 0}]]
}

new_data = {k: delist(v) for k, v in data.items()}
```

And `new_data` is

```py
{'key1': 'text',
 'key2': ['text', 'text'],
 'key3': {'key0': 0},
 'key4': {'key0': 0, 'key1': 1},
 'key5': '',
 'key6': '',
 'key7': 'text',
 'key8': {'key0': 0}}
```

Comment: This is perfect solution and more elegant then I could imagine. thank you very much. there is a little typo `{k, delist(v)...` should be `{k: delist(v)..`

Answer (score 1):

here's a one-liner for it using [np.ravel()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

```
d = {
  "key1": ["text"],
  "key2": ["text", "text"],
  "key3": [{"key0": 0}],
  "key4": [{"key0": 0, "key1": 1}],
  "key5": [],
  "key6": [[]],
  "key7": [["text"]],
  "key8": [[{"key0": 0}]]
}

out = {k: list(np.ravel(v))  if np.ravel(v).size>1 else (np.ravel(v)[0] if np.ravel(v).size==1 else '')  for k,v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'key1': 'text',
 'key2': ['text', 'text'],
 'key3': {'key0': 0},
 'key4': {'key0': 0, 'key1': 1},
 'key5': '',
 'key6': '',
 'key7': 'text',
 'key8': {'key0': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant (actually pretty ugly) but working solution to the problem in case I will not receive something smarter.

```
# input data
dct = {
  "key1": ["text"],
  "key2": ["text", "text"],
  "key3": [{"key0": 0}],
  "key4": [{"key0": 0, "key1": 1}],
  "key5": [],
  "key6": [[]],
  "key7": [["text"]],
  "key8": [[{"key0": 0}]]
}

# define function
def delist(dct):
    new_dct = {}
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if v:
            if len(v) > 1:
                new_dct[k] = v
            else:
                if v[0]:
                    if type(v[0])==list:
                        new_dct[k] = v[0][0]
                    else:
                        new_dct[k] = v[0]
                else:
                    new_dct[k] = ""         
        else:
            new_dct[k] = ""
    return new_dct

# apply function to input data
delist(dct)
```

Returns

```
{
 'key1': 'text',
 'key2': ['text', 'text'],
 'key3': {'key0': 0},
 'key4': {'key0': 0, 'key1': 1},
 'key5': '',
 'key6': '',
 'key7': 'text',
 'key8': {'key0': 0}
}
```